# Invoke a controller's function using a form button on PHP/CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to do a small proyect in PHP using CodeIgniter and NetBeans. I have this HTML view:

```
<div class="section section_with_padding" id="users"> 
        <h1>Users Access</h1> 
        <div class="half left">
            <h4>Log In</h4>
            <p>Log In here.</p>
            <div id="login">
                <form method="post" name="contact" action="Test/any">
                    <div class="left">
                        <label for="fullname">User Name:</label> 
                        <input name="fullname" type="text" class="required input_field" id="fullname" maxlength="30" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">                           
                        <label for="email">Email:</label> 
                        <input name="email" type="text" class="validate-email required input_field" id="email" maxlength="30" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label for="message">Message:</label> 
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="0" cols="0" class="required"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="half right">
            <h4>Mailing Address</h4>
            <h6><strong>Company Name</strong></h6>
            680-780 Aliquam semper dignissim,<br />
            Fusce cursus turpis lacus, 16780<br />
            Sit amet tortor

            <div class="clear h20"></div>
            <div class="img_nom img_border"><span></span>
            <iframe width="360" height="240" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Central+Park,+New+York,+NY,+USA&amp;aq=1&amp;sll=35.101934,-95.712891&amp;sspn=61.425057,135.263672&amp;vpsrc=6&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Central+Park,+New+York&amp;ll=40.771133,-73.974187&amp;spn=0.057126,0.132093&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe></div>
        </div>

        <a href="#home" class="home_btn">home</a> 
        <a href="#galeria" class="page_nav_btn previous">Prev</a>
        <a href="#admin" class="page_nav_btn next">Next</a>
    </div>
```

Don't mind the half right div, that code isn't finnished yet. My questions is this: I want to call a function inside a controller (controller Test.php, function any()). I google it and found that I could use the attribute 'action' so

```
action="my_controller/my_function"
```

But when I try that on my code, I get a nice

"Not Found

The requested URL /Project/Test/any was not found on this server."

test.php is inside Project\application\controllers

What I'm doing wrong???

Comment: you are using CI .So go with form_open() instead of <form>

Comment: You can use fork_open as @meenakshi said. And also, you can use `action = "<?php echo site_url("controller/function_name");?>"` in form.

Comment: Can you please post the code within the controller you've built?

Answer (score 5):

Add `index.php` before your controller name i.e.

```
action = "index.php/my_controller/my_function"
```

You can also remove the need for `index.php` in the URL with URL re-writing:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

as is explained in the manual: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html (under **Removing the index.php file**)

Comment: That gives me "An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested file: test.php"

Comment: try to run this function from browsers url. Is it throwing the same error?

Comment: Naaah, forget it. Test was an HTML file instead of an PHP file. Your solution worked fine. It's right to MVC standars add the index.php everytime you need to invoke a controller's function?

Comment: You can write "rewrite" rule in htaccess file of your project to avoid  writing "index.php" every time

Answer (score 3):

You can use form_open() instead of

```
<div class="section section_with_padding" id="users"> 
        <h1>Users Access</h1> 
        <div class="half left">
            <h4>Log In</h4>
            <p>Log In here.</p>
            <div id="login">
                <?php $attributes = array('class' => 'class_name', 'id' => 'id' , 'name'=>'form_name');?>
    <?php echo form_open('test/any', $attributes); ?>
                    <div class="left">
                        <label for="fullname">User Name:</label> 
                        <input name="fullname" type="text" class="required input_field" id="fullname" maxlength="30" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">                           
                        <label for="email">Email:</label> 
                        <input name="email" type="text" class="validate-email required input_field" id="email" maxlength="30" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label for="message">Message:</label> 
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="0" cols="0" class="required"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="half right">
            <h4>Mailing Address</h4>
            <h6><strong>Company Name</strong></h6>
            680-780 Aliquam semper dignissim,<br />
            Fusce cursus turpis lacus, 16780<br />
            Sit amet tortor

            <div class="clear h20"></div>
            <div class="img_nom img_border"><span></span>
            <iframe width="360" height="240" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Central+Park,+New+York,+NY,+USA&amp;aq=1&amp;sll=35.101934,-95.712891&amp;sspn=61.425057,135.263672&amp;vpsrc=6&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Central+Park,+New+York&amp;ll=40.771133,-73.974187&amp;spn=0.057126,0.132093&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe></div>
        </div>

        <a href="#home" class="home_btn">home</a> 
        <a href="#galeria" class="page_nav_btn previous">Prev</a>
        <a href="#admin" class="page_nav_btn next">Next</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that I always use for Code Igniter is this.

```
<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" />
```

This solves the problem for not only your form or AJAX requests but also to most of the CSS and JS includes.

You can then access any controller using `index.php/controller/method`

As for CSS  and JS files,

```
<script src="assets/js/jsfile.js"></script>
```

Assuming your js files are inside assets/js folder while assets is in the same folder as your index.php

Answer (score 0):

for this you use `<form>...</form>`like-

```
<form method="post" name="contact" action="<?php echo base_url();?>Test/any">
```

Comment: @Ashir you try- type in url hardcoded like- **localhost/folder_name/controller_name/Function_name** and if you not removed index.php then in url use like-**localhost/folder_name/index.php/controller_name/Function_name**

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the base_url value in your application/config/config.php?  It should be something like

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/folder_name/";
```

Then in your view you can do.

```
<form method="post" name="contact" action="<?php echo base_url();?>test/any">
```

If you have not configured Codeigniter to remove index.php them you'll have to do

```
<form method="post" name="contact" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/test/any">
```

I would also **double check** that your controller is named correctly etc.  A common mistake to make especially if you are using Netbeans is to accidentally forget the .php filename extension on your controller or something like that.